# Считать данные с файла и преобразовать в число

Tags: c#, winforms

Здравствуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста как в WinForme сделать так чтобы программа считывала данные с файла .txt и преобразовывала их в числа? А после этого эти числа сложила и предоставила результат.
В принципе со сложением я наверное и сам справлюсь, но всё равно буду благодарен за подсказ.

Comment: Дополните вопрос вашим кодом (пусть даже не рабочим).

Comment: Вы не показали ничего; не ваш код, ни даже содержимое файла, который нужно читать!

Comment: Файлы могут быть абсолютно любыми. Есть только одно условие что они содержат строки целых чисел.

Comment: Сколько в строке чисел, какой знак разделения между числами?

Comment: Одно число в одной строке, строк в файле несколько, но после или перед числами может стоять пробел, а также может попасться пустая строка!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очень легко!

```
File.ReadLines(path)       // прочитать строки
    .Select(s => s.Trim()) // обрезать пробелы в начале и в конце
    .Where(s => s != "")   // выкинуть пустые строки
    .Select(long.Parse)    // превратить строки в числа
    .Sum()                 // и всё сложить
```

Comment: Скажите ещё, это на кнопку? Или лучше создать отдельный класс и сделать так чтоб кнопка обращалась к этому классу?

Comment: @АлександрТихонов: Смотря от величины проекта. Если проект реально маленький, и это — основная его задача, можно не париться и сделать в обработчике клика (ну да, антипаттерн). А если проект немного больше, то тогда я бы, конечно, отделил это в отдельный класс-модель.

Comment: Подскажите, а как присвоить результат суммы перемененной?

Comment: @АлександрТихонов: `long sum = <тут всё выражение>;`?

Comment: @VladV то есть для вывода на экран мне нужно написать MessageBox.Show(sum);  ?

Comment: @АлександрТихонов: Ну, в качестве варианта вполне пойдёт.

Comment: @VladV не компилируется. Что здесь не так?

{

            File.ReadLines(@"C:\Users\user\Documents\test\new album\new2.txt")     
             .Select(s => s.Trim()) 
             .Where(s => s != "")   
             .Select(long.Parse)  
             .Sum();              
            MessageBox.Show(sum);
        }

Comment: @АлександрТихонов: А где у вас переменная `sum`? И что говорит компилятор?

Comment: @VladV компилятор как раз говорит что переменная sum не найдена. Я думал что ".Sum() // и всё сложить" что вы мне написали это и есть нужная переменная.

Comment: @АлександрТихонов: Ну, а вы эту переменную определили? У вас должно быть где-то `long sum = <длинное выражение из ответа>;`.